# Error in crontab entry

Tags: cron

I have been trying to make a cron entry for a shell script:

```
50 */4 * * * /path/script-file.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

aimed to run the script at HH:50 at a frequency of 4 hours. But this errors out with the message:

> crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.
>
> crontab: errors detected in input, no crontab file generated.

I removed the "/4" and the error vanished, but I know that cron does allow this format. Does anybody know what the issue could be?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: It looks strange. As a workaround you can use `0,4,8...` instead of `*/4` but still it is strange.

Comment: It works fine for me. Which system do you use? Is there some other crontab active? If you paste the line exactly as you wrote here into your crontab file, and nothing else (`50 */4 * * * /path/script-file.sh > /dev/null 2>&1`) - does the error still occurs?

Comment: What's on the previous line? What is the actual *exact* path to the script file? What OS are you using? What `crontab` implementation are you using? (`man crontab` should tell you.)

Answer (score 3):

Some `cron` implementations don't support *steps* (e.g. `*/4`) - check `man 5 crontab` on your particular system.

You can use the *list* `0,4,8,12,16,20` instead.

<del>Off-topic: If you are using bash, you could probably replace `> /dev/null 2>&1` with the shorter `&>/dev/null` or just close stdout and stderr with `1>&- 2>&-`.</del> (see @Keith Thompson's comment below)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether *you* use bash; `crontab` uses `/bin/sh` (which may be a symlink to bash on some systems, but you shouldn't depend on it).